# Jenkins Windows and MacOS slave on demand

Tags: windows, macos, jenkins, jenkins-agent, ondemand

I'm currently testing a software that runs on multiple operating system as windows / Linux and Mac OSX. We are using Jenkins pipeline to perform those actions but on physical Jenkins slaves.

I was wondering if there is a way to create MacOS and Windows slaves on the fly. We are using Docker for the linux version.

For the two other os: we first looked at virtualbox (not maintained since 4 years) and we are out of options here.
If somebody have an idea here to create slaves on the fly. That will help a lot

Comment: [The changelog](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog#v24) for VirtualBox states that in 2017 alone, 6 versions were released; the latest one being 5.1.24.

Comment: I'm sorry @StefanHanke I was talking about virtualbox jenkins pluins not virtualbox itself